# Does non-Hermitian implies at least one complex eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Ok so I'm studying linear algebra and we went trough the Spectral Theorem, including and proving the fact that for every Herimitian matrix, its eigenvalues have $0$ imaginary parts. I was wondering is it true, and if so is there a proof, that if we have non-Hermitian matrix there always exist at least one (covnersly at least $2$ as it's conjugate will also be) eigenvalue with imaginary part different from $0$. In other words the question is:

Is there any matrix $A$ such that $A^{*} \neq A$ and $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Note of caution: if the matrix has complex entries it is not true that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $\bar{\lambda}$ will be. This is only true for matrices with real entries.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I know that it is not "required" that  $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$, but is it required that there is one that violuets the equality. I'll modify my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the matrix:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$,

which is clearly non-Hermitian. Its only eigenvalue is $1$, with multiplicity $2$.

Comment: Thanks! I feel kinda stupid not being able to find an example... maybe I was looking for something way too complicated as usual.

Comment: I have lost count of the times this simple matrix has served as a counterexample to me :).

Comment: I've removed your starting "Yes!". I understand that it was an answer to "Is there any matrix...?" question, but the meaning of the title is opposite the meaning of that question and your "Yes!" may have been confusing for some future readers.